# Swift: Allow for-loop to iterate while application is in background

Tags: ios, json, for-loop, background-process

**SCENARIO**

I am working on an application that downloads a very large JSON file, sometimes 50MB. I have to parse ~40,000 documents from this JSON and store the contents in CoreData. It is not out of the ordinary for the download process alone to take at least 5 minutes (server does a lot of configuration to prepare the JSON). It is also not out of the ordinary for parsing 40,000 documents to take almost 10 minutes itself.

Short story, the user is going to be waiting 15 minutes or so to get the entire data they need to perform their job.

[image]

**ISSUE**:
*In that time the user could exit the application or device could got to sleep*.

When this happens the `for-loop` from which I am executing my parsing logic no longer iterates through the JSON to store to CoreData. This means that the user would have to continuously make sure they're device doesn't go to sleep and keep the application in the foreground for x amount of time until the download and parsing is complete.

The solution is to make these processes run in the background.

I have already included the appropriate logic to keep to the download going in the [background](https://realm.io/news/gwendolyn-weston-ios-background-networking/). But I am unsure what to do about the parsing because the `for-loop` itself is no longer doing its job.

**QUESTION**

How do I allow a `for-loop` to execute and iterate over JSON while the application is in the background?

Comment: Short answer is you can't.  Slightly longer answer is you can use `beginBackroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` to get up to 3 minutes of background execution time, but this may not be sufficient for your needs.  It sounds like you need to re-think the process.  Can the server pre-process the data so that the download doesn't take 5 minutes?  Can the server support paging so that you don't need to retrieve all of the data in one hit? Can the app hit the server when required rather than downloading all of that data?  Is CoreData the right store to use?  Can you use sqllite directly?